# Socket connection doesn't work from executable jar

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I have an application that listens to a specific UDP port and receives data over it.
When I run it through eclipse I am able to receive the data, whether I receive it from an application that is running on the same machine (sends to localhost) or from a remote machine (using the same sending application).
However, when I generate an executable jar and trying to run it, it only runs when the sending application is on the same machine (sends to localhost).

Here is the code I use to listen to the incoming data:

```
public class listenToPort implements Runnable{
        ByteArrayOutputStream mainBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            DatagramSocket Socket = null;
            try {
                Socket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
                Socket.setSoTimeout(10000);

                byte[] Input = new byte [571];
                while(true) {
                    DatagramPacket Packet = new DatagramPacket(Input, Input.length);
                    Socket.receive(Packet);
                    byte[] data = new byte[Packet.getLength()];

                    System.arraycopy(Packet.getData(), 0, data, 0, Packet.getLength());
                    try {
                        synchronized (this){
                            mainBAOS.write(data);
                        }
                    } catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 


                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }
            } 
            catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {System.out.println("No incoming data from socket, socket closed");}
            catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
            finally{
                Socket.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

What could be the reason for this odd behavior?
Any ideas on how to fix it?
Thank you for your help.

I should add that the programs do not throw any errors or anything like that, it just won't receive any data over the socket.

Comment: I suppose that the telnet does not work from the other machine to yours in the case of running the jar. Have you tried it ? Maybe your firewall(from local machine) somehow accepts connections on that port only when the application is run from Eclipse. Try to configure the firewall, or deactivate it and try again

Comment: No, have not tried telnet. But as I said, when running from eclipse the connection from the remote machine is successful.

Comment: try deactivating the firewall(if that is OK) and see if it works !

Comment: OK, fixed it. It was a firewall issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most probably a **firewall issue**. Most probably the firewall accepts connections on the given port only when the application is run using Eclipse.

Try deactivating it(if that is reasonable) to see whether it solves your problem or not !